# iOS SVN check in rules

Tags: ios, svn

I am new to iOS development. We are using SVN for code repository.

I wanted to know whether there is a way to set some rules on code check in? i.e. suppose we have a code guideline and we want everyone in the team to adher to it religiously. We can set some rules via which automatically it can be found out whether the person has followed the guidelines or not.

Something like TFS check in [policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx)?

Comment: One of the mantras of SVN architects: *it's bad to become dependent on technology as a crutch for social problems*. Also, never follow anything religiously (even if it is religion :) ). [The Way of Testivus](http://www.agitar.com/downloads/TheWayOfTestivus.pdf) should give your team a shot of perspective.

Comment: while I agree on the mantra, it is easy to forget them and it is nice to have a tool which guides me through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use on server side the so called **"hooks"**. 
Most important is the pre-commit-hook

You can found them on the server inside the repository in the directory **hooks**

You can place any executable there and it will be called during commit. There is a svncommand called **svnlook** which you can use to look directly into the transaction to be committed.

In each repository there is one example for each hook SVN provides. These templates showing a sample implementation with some meanigful bash script.

[more infos about hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)